# table view dictionary array issue

Tags: arrays, dictionary, tableview

i'm trying to get my tableview to index my array correctly but it keeps randomising the dictionary values shown in the table view . Where am I going wrong?

code is as follows:

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! _VCTableViewCell
    // Schemes

    let kbSchemes: [Int: [String]] = [
        0: ["1","2","3","4","5","6"],
        1: ["1","2","3","4","5","6"],
        2: ["1a","1b","2a","2b","3a","3b","4"],
        3: ["1a","1b","1c","1d","1e","1f"],
        4: ["1a","1b","1c","2a","2b","2c"]
    ]
    let randomSchemeIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(kbSchemes.count)))
    let schemeArray = kbSchemes[randomSchemeIndex]


    // Exercise, Sets & Reps
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(kbDirectory.count)))
    let dictValues = Array(kbDirectory.values)
    let randomArray = dictValues[randomIndex]
    let randomArrayIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomArray.count)))
    let randomValue = randomArray[randomArrayIndex]
    let dictKeys = Array(kbDirectory.keys)

    // cell control
    cell.exerciseLabel?.text = dictKeys[randomIndex]
    cell.setRepLabel?.text = randomValue
    cell.numberLabel?.text = schemeArray?[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
```

I would also like to be able the .count property for the returned kbSchemeArray later on in numberOfRowsInSection but am having issues getting it into the correct scope. any suggestions and/or advice appreciated.

Comment: Please learn how a table view works (cue model-view-controller). Your approach *... later on in numberOfRowsInSection* is totally wrong. `numberOfRowsInSection` is always called **before** `cellForRowAt..`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, I've already called it before and just returned an Int until I get my table to working property. I'm wondering why my indexPath is incorrect for the kbSchemes random array. Is that something to do with what you've mentioned? Or something else?